# Unexpected Token error in Login Function

Tags: java, android, authentication

I have written a Login function in Android Studio. There is an error in "else" UnExpected Token.

```
else {
    displaymessage.setText("Login is unsuccessful");
}
```

The code as follows:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText etName;
    private EditText etPassword;
    private Button Login;
    private TextView displaymessage;    

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        etName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etName);
        etPassword= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
        Login= (Button)findViewById(R.id.BtnLogin);
        displaymessage=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.displaymessage);

        Login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String Name = String.valueOf(etName.getText());
                String password = String.valueOf(etPassword.getText());

                if (Name.equals("Ammad") && password.equals("Ammad"))
                    displaymessage.setText("Login is successfull");
            }
            else
            {
                displaymessage.setText("Login is unsuccessful");
            }        
        });    
}
```

Comment: if  statement has no start parenthesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

open/close if statement properly.

```
    if (Name.equals("Ammad") && password.equals("Ammad"))
        {
                displaymessage.setText("Login is successfull");
        }
        else
        {
            displaymessage.setText("Login is unsuccessful");
        }
```